# Django-dynamic-scraper unable to scrape the data

Tags: python, django, scrapy, django-dynamic-scraper

I am new to using dynamic scraper, and I have used the following sample for  learning[open_news](https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper/tree/master/example_project/open_news). I have everything set up but it keeps me showing the same error: `dynamic_scraper.models.DoesNotExist: RequestPageType matching query does not exist.`

```
2015-11-20 18:45:11+0000 [article_spider] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Main_page>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/base.py", line 825, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/task.py", line 645, in _tick
    taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/task.py", line 491, in _oneWorkUnit
    result = next(self._iterator)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynamic_scraper/spiders/django_spider.py", line 378, in parse
    rpt = self.scraper.get_rpt_for_scraped_obj_attr(url_elem.scraped_obj_attr)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dynamic_scraper/models.py", line 98, in get_rpt_for_scraped_obj_attr
    return self.requestpagetype_set.get(scraped_obj_attr=soa)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
dynamic_scraper.models.DoesNotExist: RequestPageType matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by "REQUEST PAGE TYPES" is missing.
Each "SCRAPER ELEMS" must have it's own "REQUEST PAGE TYPES".

To solve this problem, please follow the steps below:

1. Login admin page (usually http://localhost:8000/admin/)
2. Go to Home › Dynamic_Scraper › Scrapers › Wikinews Scraper (Article)
3. Click on "Add another Request page type" under "REQUEST PAGE TYPES"
4. Create 4 "REQUEST PAGE TYPES" in total for each "(base (Article))", "(title (Article))", "(description (Article))" and "(url (Article))"

**"REQUEST PAGE TYPES" Settings**

All "Content type" are "HTML"

All "Request type" are "Request"

All "Method" are "Get"

For "Page type", just assign them in sequence like

(base (Article)) | Main Page

(title (Article)) | Detail Page 1

(description (Article) | Detail Page 2

(url (Article)) | Detail Page 3

After the steps above you should fix "DoesNotExist: RequestPageType" error.

However, "ERROR: Mandatory elem title missing!" would come up!

To solve this. I suggest you changing all "REQUEST PAGE TYPE" in "SCRAPER ELEMS" to "Main Page" including "title (Article)".

And then change the XPath as follow:

(base (Article)) | //td[@class="l_box"]

(title (Article)) | span[@class="l_title"]/a/@title

(description (Article) | p/span[@class="l_summary"]/text()

(url (Article)) | span[@class="l_title"]/a/@href

After all, run `scrapy crawl article_spider -a id=1 -a do_action=yes` on command prompt.
You should be able to crawl the "Article".
You may check it from Home › Open_News › Articles

Enjoy~

Answer (score 1):

I might be late for the party, but hopefully my solution could be somewhat helpful for those coming across later.

@alan-nala solution works well. However, it basically skips the detail page **scraping**.

Here is how you can take full advantage of the detail page **scraping**.

First, go to **Home › Dynamic_Scraper › Scrapers › Wikinews Scraper (Article)**
and [add those](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXkV8.png) in **Request page types**.

Second, make sure your elements look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmMeg.png) in **SCRAPER ELEMS**.

Now, you can run the manual scraping command according to the doc

```
scrapy crawl article_spider -a id=1 -a do_action=yes
```

Well, you are likely to encounter an error as mentioned by @alan-nala

**"ERROR: Mandatory elem title missing!"**

Please pay attention to [the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsDYA.png), I have a message indicating the script is **"Calling DP2 URL for..."** in my case.

Finally, you can go back to **SCRAPER ELEMS** and change **Request page type** of the element "title (Article)" to "**Detail Page 2**" instead of "Detail Page 1".

Save your settings and run the scrapy command again.

Note: Your "Detail Page #" might vary.

By the way, I have also prepared [a short tutorial](https://github.com/0xboz/django_dynamic_scraper_tutorial) hosted by GitHub, in case you need more details on this topic.